# How to view multiple projects in one window in IntelliJ IDEA IDE?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse IDE you have the concept of "workspaces" allowing you to manage/view your projects in one side pane easily and allowing you to switch between projects easily.

As i gather IntelliJ doesn't have that feature because everytime when i open a new project it always asks to either open in a different window or same window? And in the latter option it overrides my existing open project.

Comment: You answered your own question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right; IntelliJ simply doesn't have this functionality.  Each project is opened in a single window, either overwriting your current window or spawning a new window.

If you feel that this sort of behavior is something you want, then feel encouraged to put in a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new empty project and import into it the modules from the other projects.

This works for me, although is not exactly the same as what you're trying to achieve. Note that you will lose (e.g. have to specify manually) the specific projects' settings.